# Understanding a proof about contraction mapping theorem

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, supremum-and-infimum, fixed-point-theorems, banach-fixed-point

[image]

The above is the question, and here is a solution:
[image]

In the solution above, I do not quite understand:

Why the assumptions that $C[a,b]$ is complete with the sup metric guarentee that $Tf\in C[a,b]$?

Why do we say that $|(T f)(x) − (T h)(x)| ≤ \int^b_a
|k(x, y)||f(y) − h(y)| dy$? I think it is $|(T f)(x) − (T h)(x)| = |\int^b_a
k(x, y)[f(y) − h(y)] dy|= \int^b_a
|k(x, y)||f(y) − h(y)| dy$. Is that correct?

Could someone please explain? Thanks!

Comment: The assumption on $k$ guarantee (by fundamental properties of the integral) that $Tf$ is continuous. Completeness only plays a role in concluding the existence of a fixed point for the constructed contraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T$ is continuous since it is the composition of continuous functions: pointwise multiplication by $k(x,y)$ (which is continuous), integration, and addition.

Hence, $T \circ f:C[a,b] \to C[a,b]$ will be continuous as well.

The completeness is used to conclude that there is a fixed point, by the Banach fixed point theorem.

In the last inequality, this is just an application of the "[triangle inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284322/the-triangle-inequality-for-integrals)," so that we bring the absolute value inside of the integral:

$$\left| \int_a^b g(x) dx\right| \leq \int_{a}^{b} |g(x)| dx.$$

your last equality should be an inequality.