# Function not piecewise continuous

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals, riemann-integration, piecewise-continuity

I would like to find a function $f$ such that
$$
\left|\int_a^b f(x)\ dx \right| > \int_a^b |f(x)|\ dx  
$$
where the integral should be understand in the Riemann sense.

Of course, $f$ shouldn't be piecewise continuous.

Comment: there is no such function, it can be proved that the opposite is always true.

Answer (score 0):

Your inequality is always false. For example see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3031025/integral-absolute-value-proof) for a proof of the opposite inequality.