# How do I prove that the modulus of the integral is lesser or equal the integral of modulus?

Tags: calculus

I do understand that because of the limits of integration the integral of |f(x)| can be negative, but the modulus of the integral can't. But I don't know how to prove the statement.

$$ \left| \int_a^b f(x) \, dx \right| \leq \int_a^b |f(x)| \, dx $$

Comment: Shouldn't the inequality be the other way? As in: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3031025/732532

Comment: I do not think this inequality is true

Comment: This is not in general true: take $a < b$ and $f(x)$ to be $-1$ on the first half of the interval and $1$ in the other.

Comment: @michaelMorrow you're right. It should be the other way. Your link has the answer I couldn''t find. Many thanks

Comment: First thing that comes to my mind is Riemann sums and triangle inequality.

Comment: You probably want to edit the title too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, as pointed out in the comments we must require that $a \leq b,$ so that there is no distinction between signed and unsigned integration: a more proper way to write the inequality might be

$$\left|\int_{[a,b]} f(x) dx\right| \leq \int_{[a,b]} |f(x)| dx$$

From there, the concept of flipping up the regions where $f$ is negative posed by the other answer is good intuition for why we would expect this to be true, and if we’re using the Lebesgue definition of the integral then that exact argument gives us a good path for a proof. Letting $I$ be our interval $[a, b]$ consider that by definition

$$\int_I f(x) dx = \int_I f^+(x) dx - \int_I f^-(x) dx$$

where $f^+$ and $f^-$ are the positive and negative parts of $f$ respectively, so defining measurable sets $A = \{x \in I: f(x) \geq 0\}$ and $B = \{x \in I: f(x) < 0\}$ we have

$$\int_I f(x) dx = \int_A |f(x)| dx - \int_B |f(x)| dx$$

and by the additivity of measure we have as well that

$$\int_I |f(x)| dx = \int_A |f(x)| dx + \int_B |f(x)| dx$$

and because $|f(x)| \geq 0$ we have by monotonicity that its integrals are greater than $0$, so they’re equal to their own absolute values. So, letting $I_A$ and $I_B$ represent the integrals of $|f(x)|$ on $A$ and $B,$ our theorem can be rewritten as

$$|I_A - I_B| \leq |I_A| + |I_B|$$

which is just the triangle inequality.

Different definitions of the integral would require a different proof, but the same idea of reducing to the triangle inequality is useful, the path to get there just changes slightly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I had completely forgotten this quesiton. Yes, I got it. Thanks!

Comment: @CarlosEduardo No problem, sorry the answer couldn’t have been a bit more timely for you. I’d actually be curious to know how your question ended up getting found, I saw it in recent questions because of another answer (now deleted) so I guess they were probably just looking through unanswered calculus questions? In any case I’m glad to help you now if you were still curious