# I need help with prove "If the partial derivatives are bounded then the function is Lipschitz".

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

Can anyone help me to prove the next statements?

1. Let $f:\mathbb R^n$$\to$$\mathbb R$ such that the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}$ exists at each point and $E$ $\subseteq$ $\mathbb R^n$. So, if the partial derivatives are bounded in $E$, then $f$ Satisfies the **Lipschitz condition**:

   **$|f(x)-f(y)|$$\le$$M|x-y|$**
2. Let $E$ $\subseteq$ $\mathbb R^n$ open subset and $f: E$$\to$$\mathbb R$ Differentiability and Continuous then $f$ Satisfies the **Lipschitz condition*

Thank you.

Comment: I think the left side of your lipschitz condition should use $y$ too..

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not true, without further assumption on the set $E$ - for example, if $E=\{x,y\}$ contains exactly two points there is no way to obtain a Lipschitz bound from knowledge of the gradient of the function at just those two points.

On the other hand, if $E$ is path-connected then you can prove the result by picking a path from $x$ to $y$ and integrating the gradient of $f$ along this path, using the [triangle inequality for integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284322/the-triangle-inequality-for-integrals) to get the Lipschitz bound. To be more precise, you will need to know that the length of the path is bounded by a multiple of the distance from $x$ to $y$, which can be arranged as long as $E$ is not too pathological. For instance, if $E$ is convex you can just pick the straight line path.

Comment: But what about it? 

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1257553/a-multivariate-function-with-bounded-partial-derivatives-is-lipschitz

Comment: That's a different question than what you asked, since yours is more general. In that question $E=\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!! I added one more question..can you help me with that?

Comment: Please post your separate question in another post instead of adding on to here. If your question is answered, please mark it as such.

Comment: I can't post more question because I reached my limit.